# cloudera cluster node roles

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I need to ran simple benchmark test on my cloudera CDH4 cluster setup. 
My cloudera cluster setup (CDH4) has 4 nodes, A, B, C and D
I am using cloudera manager FREE edition to manage cloudera services.
Each node is configured to perform multiple roles as stated below.
A : NameNode, JobTrackerNode, regionserver, SecondaryNameNode, DataNode, TaskTrackerNode
B : DataNode, TaskTrackerNode
C : DataNode, TaskTrackerNode
D : DataNode, TaskTrackerNode

My first question is, Can one node be NameNode and DataNode?
Is this setup all right?
My second question is, on cloudera manager UI, i can see many services running but i am not sure whether i need all this services or not?
Services running on my setup are : 
hbase1
hdfs1
mapreduce1
hue1
oozie1
zookeeper1

Do i need only hdfs1 and mapreduce1 services. If yes how can i remove other services?

Cloud and hadoop concept is new to me so pardon me if some of my assumptions are illogical or wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

answer to your first question is yes. but you would never do that in production as NameNode needs sufficient amount of RAM. people usually run only NameNode+JobTracker on their master node. it is also better to run SecondarNameNode on a different machine.

coming to your second question, Cloudera Manager is not only Hadoop. it's a complete package that includes several Hadoop sub-projects like HBase(a NOSQL DB), Oozie(a Workflow engine) etc. and these are the processes which yo see on the UI.

If you wanna play just with Hadoop, HDFS and MapReduce are sufficient. You can stop rest of the processes easily from the UI itself. it won't do any harm to your Hadoop cluster.

HTH